# How use OAuth2 of Discord in a Android Application make in java

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, discord, request

I would like to use discord's oauth2 in my application made in java, but I don't really have an idea how to do it.

I tried to use HttpClient but it didn't work because I couldn't use Intent.ACTION_VIEW and make the request with following the redirect at the same time.

So if someone could explain to me how to do it (knowing that I am new to java). Thanks

Comment: Have you read the oAuth documentation for Android? https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate

Comment: Oh, no, sorry, I hadn't seen the documentation. I'll try to figure it out and let you know if there's a problem.

Comment: So I looked but in their tutorial they already had the code (if I understood correctly), I just need to follow the redirect after the person has clicked on authorized. Because I made sure that in my api the redirection link sends me the information directly ("access_token",..) and when I have the token my application makes another request to obtain the information on its user (username, avatar, etc.).